# BLOWING BREAKERS

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, gfci

I have an outlet just outside my house, runs a little underground through white pvc piping. The one outlet controls two sump pumps.  One for my main underground water as my house is built below the water table, the other is for my septic tank.

The outlet has caused a number of problems. Last time it tripped the breaker water back up from my septic and burnt out the wiring.

I pulled the main wiring out and replaced it with my old hot tub wiring. Runs from my main panel of double 15 breakers to a gfi breaker with 40amp in it. The receptacle outlet is 15-20 Amp I believe.

It works for a while then the main pump keeps tripping the GFCI breaker. I plug that pump into an extension cord running from a normal outlet in the house and no problem. I need the outside outlet to constantly work or I have severe water problems in the house.

Most recently a flood in basement of 6 inches of water destroying my water tank.

Comment: Kinda hard to follow all that. Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: What I get out of it was he had a triping problem so he fed 15 amp outlets from the old 40amp GFCI breaker and wire for the hot tub, but he's got a ground fault so bigger and dangerous didn't help, it's still tripping.  But it doesn't from the extension cord to a non-gfci circuit in the house that he tested.

Comment: Karen, welcome to Home Improvement Stack Exchange.  I trust you don't mind my reformatting your text a bit so it is more bite-size.  Please take a moment and view the tour at:  https://diy/stackexchange.com/Tour to see how we generally work.  Focused questions will generate the most useful answers.

Comment: Karen, please edit your question to end with a very specific Q.  I suggest:  Why is my pump tripping the GFCI?  or something like that.  I won't change your content - that's up to you.

Comment: Do sump pumps need to be on GFCI?  Is that in code now?

Answer (score 1):

If sounds to me like either one or both of the pumps you have plugged into the exterior GFI receptacle are nearing the end of their usable life.  The GFI receptacle is simply doing what it is supposed to do, tripping when it 'sees' a bleed to ground on the loads it is delivering.  As the pumps age the bearing on their motors wear and get sloppy.  The insulation on the windings starts to break down. All of this contributes to leakage current.  This is what trips a GFI receptacle.  These pumps have a definite life expectancy.  New pumps will likely make your problems go away for 10-15-years.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you hard wire the pumps they don't have to be on GFCI. Then if they trip a breaker they are definitely broke.

All exterior 125 volt 15 or 20 amp receptacles are required to be on GFCI.

From the 2017 National Electrical Code

> **210.8(A) Dwelling Units.**  All 125-volt, single-phase, 15- and 20-ampere receptacles installed in the locations specified in 210.8(A)(1) through (10) shall have ground-fault circuit-interrupter protection for personnel.

...

> (3) Outdoors

Good luck!

Comment: I agree but it depends on the location , my state Oregon has an exception to the GFCI requirements in 210.8 allowing sump pumps to not be GFCI protected if the outlet is marked not GFCI protected.